# Fields_for without a do loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, fields-for

Is there a way to do `fields_for` a `has_many` association without looping through all the associated items?

---

I have a very similar situation to that discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884704/how-to-get-rails-build-and-fields-for-to-create-only-a-new-record-and-not-includ):

I have a `Person` model, with several related models (`Address`, `Phone number`, `Jobtitle`...), and on the form I'd only like to create new records. 
The new record should be pre-filled from the existing record. I have a helper function which catches the right data, I just want `fields_for` to display that without having to go through the do loop.

Comment: What "do loop" are you talking about?

Comment: Probably cycling through existing data :/

Comment: `<%= f.fields_for :addresses do |a| %>` enumerates all addresses for that person. I don't want to do that, I have already queried the data elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you need:

```
#app/models/person.rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :addresses
   has_many :phone_numbers
   has_many :job_titles

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, :phone_numbers, :job_titles
end

#app/controllers/people_controller.rb
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
   def edit
       @person = Person.find params[:id]
       @person.addresses.build #-> this adds onto the existing "addresses" for that person
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use the following:

```
#app/views/people/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |a| %>
       <% if a.object.new_record? %>
          <%= a.text_field :street %>
          <%= a.text_field :town %>
       <% end %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This should only output the inputs for the `new` associative object (the one you built). It's a bit hacky, but I get your problem -- you *only* want to show the new inputs (the existing ones should not show).

Saving this will *add* an associative record to your `Person` object. The existing ones will still exist.

Comment: This is essentially what I'm doing, although I found that using `a.object.new_record?` didn't work in all situations and would wipe out data during the form round trip if validation failed.  I'm selecting the correct data into a variable called data_object and then checking `a.object.attributes == data_object.attributes`.  This is the 'looping' behaviour I'd like to remove.

Comment: You mean you want to keep your code lean, thus removing the looping functionality which makes it scan through the already assigned attributes?

Comment: You've hit the nail precisely on the head.  The problem is that in this project the People model has 16 associations, each of which might have 5 or 6 historical records. I've got a page load time north of 10s because of this enumeration :(

Comment: I think the solution may be to introduce a `has_one :new_address `relationship. My problem with this approach before was that you can have two addresses of different types (home and office, say) and so this meant this approach was a non starter. I am refactoring for STI in this case, and we'll see if it works.

Comment: Yes, please let me know if it does - I am interested! Thanks for the heads-up; I'm sure there must be a way to do this... the difference between the new & populated objects are pretty stark

Comment: It turns out you can't have a `has_one :new_address` relationship if you have a `has_many :addresses` relationship, as doing `@person.build_new_address` will try to update the last historical address record, alter it's PK and set its FK to NULL amongst other things.

Comment: Please remove the one if the "if" on the line " if if a.object.new_record?". Other than that, that was exactly what I was looking for :-) Cheers