# How to get rails fields_for to build a new association IF one doesn't current exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm referencing this stack overflow post: [How to get Rails build and fields_for to create only a new record and not include existing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884704/how-to-get-rails-build-and-fields-for-to-create-only-a-new-record-and-not-includ)

In my case, I have this:

```
<%= form.fields_for :campaign_schedule, @campaign.build_campaign_schedule do |campaign_schedule| %>
```

If `@campaign` does not already have a `campaign_schedule` then this builds a new `campaign_schedule` and shows the text_fields in the form so the user can provide the data for the new `campaign schedule`.

However, what if the `@campaign` has an existing `campaign_schedule` already? I get an error using this `fields_for` form, stating this:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved (Failed to remove the existing associated
>   campaign_schedule. The record failed to save after its foreign key was
>   set to nil.):

I'm assuming it's because a `campaign_scheduled` already exists for `@campaign` and it's trying to build a new one.

Should I just simply go with something like this?

```
<% if @campaign.campaign_schedule.nil? %>
    <%= form.fields_for :campaign_schedule, @campaign.build_campaign_schedule do |campaign_schedule| %>
<% else %>
    <%= form.fields_for :campaign_schedule, do |campaign_schedule| %>
<% end %>
```

Or is there a better way to do it? I basically have these associations:

```
#app/models/campaign.rb
class Campaign < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :campaign_schedule

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :campaign_schedule
end
```

and

```
#app/models/campaign_schedule.rb
class CampaignSchedule < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :campaign
end
```

**EDIT**

Looks like my `if` condition wouldn't work anyway, because the `end` to that condition conflicts with the `form.fields_for` condition so that wouldn't work. I guess I need to figure out how to manipulate `form.fields_for` to build an association only if one doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build a new compaign schedule if nil on the controller action:

```
def edit
  @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:id])
  @campaign.build_campaign_schedule unless @campaign.campaign_schedule
end
```

then you should be able to do:

```
<%= form.fields_for :campaign_schedule do |campaign_schedule| %>
```

Comment: Thank you. This does the trick! I actually built a helper but I like this idea a lot better. I think this should be in the `new` action though right? Don't want to build a campaign schedule if you're editing an existing one (which will have one)

Comment: You can do that in both actions, I've used `edit` just to put the code on a context and not just a single line of code, you know better than anyone where you need the relevant piece of code (build a new one if it does not exists).